# PHP: Parse all data from mysql where the 3rd and 4th digit of the id

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, substring

I have a mysql table with some weird id's like this:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╗
║   ║     id     ║   user_id   ║  hours_a  ║   hours_b   ║  hours_c  ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 1 ║ 010120149  ║     9       ║    10     ║     6       ║    23     ║
║ 2 ║ 0212201310 ║     10      ║    2      ║     8       ║    10     ║
║ 3 ║ 021220138  ║     8       ║    1      ║     4       ║     9     ║
║ 4 ║ 020120149  ║     9       ║    3      ║     8       ║    10     ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╝
```

I am trying to parse the total hours for user id 9, for the month January and year 2014. As you can see from the table, that is the first and last row.

For example, `01 01 2014 9` is the first row's ID of which represents **DD/MM/YYYY/ID**.

I want to be able to retrieve all hours (hours_a, hours_b & hours_c **separately**) for **user_id = 9** where **day = 01 - 31**(loop through all days?), **month = 01** and **year = 2014**.

To be exported in something like this:

```
{"userid":"9","month":"01","year":"2014","total_hours_a":"13","total_hours_b":"14","total_hours_c":"33"}
```

The ID's represent Day, Month, Year and Userid as such:
[image]

---

### Currently what I'm doing

Currently I'm selecting all the table:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `weird_table` WHERE `id` LIKE 9";
```

Printing it to encoded json:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$temp = 0;
$json = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $json[$temp]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $json[$temp]['userid'] = $row['userid'];
    $json[$temp]['hours_a'] = $row['hours_a'];
    $json[$temp]['hours_b'] = $row['hours_b'];
    $json[$temp]['hours_c'] = $row['hours_c'];
    }

$temp++;
}

print json_encode($json);
mysql_close();
```

and then client side (as i am a front-end developer), i mix&match & sum it up and get the results I want. Instead of doing all this hassle and giving the user so much cpu pain; i would like the server to do the work and print me exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I highly recommend if at all possible to restructure the database. This is very poor design. you already have the user_id so having the user_id again in the id is storing duplicate data which is not normalized, then you should store dates in regular date formats such as DATE or DATETIME.

Comment: Unfortunately I am working on a database not designed by me, of which I have no access/power of re-structuring it. I am working with what I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, (hours_a + hours_b + hours_c) totalHours
FROM weird_table 
WHERE user_id = 9 AND 
      STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(id, 1, 8), '%d%m%Y') BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31'
```

**OR**

```
SELECT *, (hours_a + hours_b + hours_c) totalHours 
FROM weird_table 
WHERE user_id = 9 AND SUBSTRING(id, 3, 6) = '012014'
```

**OR**

```
SELECT *, (hours_a + hours_b + hours_c) totalHours
FROM weird_table 
WHERE user_id = 9 AND 
      YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(id, 1, 8), '%d%m%Y')) = 2014 AND 
      MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(id, 1, 8), '%d%m%Y')) = 1
```

Comment: WHERE id = 9  OR WHERE `user_id`=9

Comment: there is already user_id there, then why SUBSTRING(id, 8, LENGTH(id)) = 9, you can directly call where user_id = :)

Comment: How can I then sum all hours_a, hours_b and hours_c together?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
select userid,SUBSTRING(id, 3, 2) ,SUBSTRING(id, 5, 4),hours_a,hours_b, hours_c
FROM weird_table 
WHERE userid = 9 AND SUBSTRING('010120149', 3, 6) = '012014';
```

and the retrived rows hours value can be simply added up.

Comment: This wouldn't work as its very precise. Substring 010120149 wouldn't work for any other case if the userid is different

Comment: @jQuerybeast we will just need string that has current month and date

Answer (score -1):

By using CPU of the Server, it means to me, PHP also runns on the server, so I would do the work by the PHP-script.

Firstly Split the ID into MM, DD, YYYY and then use it to fill a Sum-Array.